# next js server side rendering not working when dynamic import in function

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

i try to implement dynamic import in my next js project

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import Link from 'next/link'

import { GetStaticProps, GetStaticPaths, GetServerSideProps } from 'next'

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}


export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    return {
        props: { 'type': getRandomInt(3) + 1 ,
        }
    }
}

function Home({ type }) {
    const BodyDefault = dynamic(() => import(`components/${type}/a`));
    return (
        <div>
            <BodyDefault></BodyDefault>
            <Link href="/other">
                go to other
            </Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

it work well, but server side rendering is not working !!

(i checked that when show page source in chrome )

is it impossible change dynmic import component with serverside props??

thanks